# Why I cannot make a call between Twilio accounts through browsers?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I have two upgraded Twilio accounts, I can make calls to/from mobile phones for both of this accounts.

I have bought phone numbers, created TwiML applications and new API keys on both accounts, setup voice URLs to my web app, which returns the following twiml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Thanks for calling to <client></Say>
    <Dial callerId="<caller phone number>">
        <Number><client phone number></Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

But, I cannot make a call between those two accounts when I try to call through browsers, from one browser to another by using my JS application which is a client of twilio-client.min.js.

When I call from one browser to another by Twilio phone number I can see in consoles that access tokens are generated and Twilio.Device objects are initialized properly for both web clients.
Then I hear ringing and tones, I accept the call and then I hear "Thanks for calling to " from my twiml, but then call drops every time.

I do not understand what problem is.
Can anybody help me with that problem?

Thanks.

Update.
Call logs
[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White there is nothing special to provide, JS code for Twilio client can be found in standard example. The question is not about programming issue, but about the possibility to make voice calls from one paid Twilio account to another by using phone numbers, not client aliases, and through browsers, I mean from one browser on one PC to another browser on another PC over internet. Of course by using my web application which is almost the same with standard Twilio JS example.

Answer (score 0):

Is the callerID you are setting in the Twilio Markup Language (TwiML) another Twilio number in your account or a verified callerID? Also check the [Debugger](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/debugging-tools) for errors and verify the destination number you are dialing is covered by the [Voice Geographic permissions](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180228-International-Voice-Dialing-Geographic-Permissions-Geo-Permissions-and-How-They-Work) of the calling account.

[Adding a Verified Phone Number or Caller ID with Twilio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio)

Comment: Hi @Alan, thanks for suggestions, and yes the callerID is my Twilio number of my account. Debugger shows that all the calls are ok, DIRECTION - Incoming, FROM +1850918.., TO +1813343..., TYPE - Phone, STATUS - Completed, DURATION - 3 sec.

Comment: Ok, take a look at your Call Logs, do you see the 2nd call leg (the one generated by the TwiML you shared above)? Is there any entry for it? Also, verify the TwiML at the URL, is the destination number in E.164 format (in the US +1 in front).

Comment: Please look at my post I have attached a screen. All phone numbers in E.164 format.

Comment: Here is a little video about how it's going.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/13oNVCiSd41jmsT2Wf6xK_6OWsT9ZjXn-/view?usp=sharing
"Voice test message" - it is <Say> tag in my TwiML application. "Thanks for calling..." - it is <Say> tag in my TwiML Bean assigned to called phone number voice_url.